# UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey is returning nil

Tags: swift, uiviewanimationtransition

So, I am using the [Elastic Transition](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ElasticTransition) pod (Cocoapods), and when I transition my app crashes because the `UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey` key is `nil`. I am really confused as to why that value would be `nil`. What are some probable causes and solutions to resolving this error?

So here is some of my code for when I am transitioning into the next view controller:

```
func handleTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    transition.sticky = true
    transition.transformType = .TranslateMid
    transition.showShadow = true
    transition.edge = .Left
    transition.startingPoint = sender.center
    performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    segue.destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = transition
    segue.destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
}
```

Then, when it is trying to transition my app crashes complaining that this line of code (in Elastic Transition) is returning `nil`:

```
transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
```

Comment: can you please share some code

Comment: @SashaKozachuk I updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried using presentViewController instead of performSegue?

Comment: @Blip if I do that then the animation is gone completely and replaced with the default animation.

Comment: @Harish There's a tutorial on the official ElasticTransition Github page (https://github.com/lkzhao/ElasticTransition) that explains how to make it work. Have you checked that out? Are you doing a modal segue or a nav controller segue?

Comment: @Blip I am doing a push segue. And, I am kind of confused about why this is happening because I actually had to create a new project and copy all of the source code to the new project because I was experiencing some issues with the old project. In the old project, my code was working flawlessly, but now it isn't.

Comment: @Harish Oh! I think I know where the problem is. The ElasticTransition Github page said that when doing push segues, you need to set `transition` as the `navigationController`'s `delegate`. Why don't you try that and see if it works?

Comment: @Blip I don't have a navigation controller, do I need to add one?

Comment: @Harish If you have a push segue you need to have a navigation controller. If you do modal segue then no need for nav controller.

Comment: @Blip Ok, great! If you want just answer this question, and I will mark it as accepted. I think that was what was causing the view controller key to return nil.

Comment: @Harish Sure, but does my suggestion work though?

Comment: @Blip, It does. I did add the navigation controller, and set the delegate. It works now. However, I am just confused about why it wasn't an issue in the old project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ElasticTransition Github page](https://github.com/lkzhao/ElasticTransition), if a view controller is presented ***modally*** with elastic transition, then the destination view controller's `transitioningDelegate` needs to be set to `ElasticTransition` and `modalPresentationStyle` to `.Custom`. However, if the view controller is pushed onto a navigation controller stack using the elastic transition, then only the `navigationController?.delegate` needs to be set to `ElasticTransition`.

After some chatting, @Harish told me that he uses a push segue. However, the code in `prepareForSegue` is the setup code for when one presents a view controller *modally*. That is likely the reason why `UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey` returns nil. So I believe the solution is to set the `navigationController`'s `delegate` to `ElasticTransition` somewhere, and remove the code in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help :)